# How can I make display: table-cell be the same height with my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<article id="articlesss" class="container_12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 2em; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div class="grid_6" style="display: table-cell;">
            <div class="block-border">
                <div style="background-color: red; height: 100px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_6" style="display: table-cell;">
            <div class="block-border">
                <div style="background-color: red; height: 200px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

I am using display: table-row because I heard that this would make my DIVs work like table cells and I was wanting the DIVs to be the same height. However it seems like the first grid_6 grid has a small height while the second has at least 100px. How can I make it fill to be the same height?

Here's an example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8GEv/)

Comment: Give same height to first grid :)

Comment: This works. You just can't see the second element because there is no style > http://jsfiddle.net/U8GEv/

Comment: Wait wait I can't give a height to the first grid. Either grid could be any height. I was just putting that div there as a test.

Comment: Are you wanting the inner content of the table cells to be the same height or just the table cells?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="block-border">
        <div style="background-color: red; height: 100px;"></div>
```

You have set the height of second element i.e Height = 100px .

Set the height to both  the div elements .

Comment: Wait I cannot do that. This is just an example. Both DIVs can have different amounts of text. Use of the table style allows cell heights to match so I am not sure why they are not doing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both grid_6 elements are the same height. The reason why you see one red rectangle larger than the other is you are coloring the inside divs. If you put the color on the grid_6 elements - they are the same. http://jsfiddle.net/A7yXc/

```
<article id="articlesss" class="container_12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 2em; display: table;">
<div style="display: table-row">
    <div class="grid_6" style="display: table-cell; background-color: red;">
        <div class="block-border">
            <div style="height: 100px;">das</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6" style="display: table-cell; background-color: red;">
        <div class="block-border">
            <div style="height: 200px;">das</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```